# File_get_Contents ignore error

Tags: php

```
$url = 'xxxxxxxxx';
$result = file_get_contents($url);
$stuff = json_decode($result, true);
if (false !== ($contents = $stuff)) {
echo $contents;
} else {
//do nothing
}
```

If query doesnt return any result, I want to show nothing

Instead I am getting

```
Warning: file_get_contents(xxxx) [function.file-get-contents]: 
failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.0 400 Bad Request in /home/xxxxx/xxx.php on line 4
```

Comment: I usually don't suggest this, but use the `@` operator.  `$result = @file_get_contents($url);`

Comment: And then make sure you check for a result before using it

Comment: As Rocket said, use `@` before the function name, and use the [error_get_last](http://www.php.net/manual/es/function.error-get-last.php) function or [$php_errormsg](http://www.php.net/manual/es/reserved.variables.phperrormsg.php) variable if you want to see the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `@` before the function or set `error_reporting(0)` (not recommended since all errors will be suppressed).

Comment: Where to set it . New to php

Comment: I would not suggest setting error_reporting(0) as it will stop all errors showing up, IE it will hide the symptoms not cure the problem. You are better off with @ as suggested by Rocket Hazmat as at least then you will see any other errors that occur

Comment: Just add `error_reporting(0)` above your code. Adding a '@' will be 'better', all other errors willn't be suppressed.

Comment: How will try/catch help, this is a PHP warning, not an exception that can be caught.

Comment: @preinheimer You're right, adding an error handler to throw an exception will be too much for this case I guess.